# Is it possible to change input type date display format?

Tags: html, date, input

I am using a simple html5 input tag with type="date". The date format is showing as below[image]

but I want the date format to be like "dd-mm-yyyy". Is it possible or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the style can't be changed at the moment, the browser has full control over how it displays this element.

**A Possible Solution (Untested)**
You can try out a normal text input tag and modify it so the user has to replace the format by highlighting it and entering text (seen done before, not sure how though.)